# ListBox long items hints

Tags: delphi, vcl

There's a ListBox with some long items. These long items are getting beyond the right edge of the ListBox and here comes an idea to show hints for such items when the mouse is over them.

I've found an example: (from http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_4.htm)

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseMove (Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer) ;
var lstIndex : Integer ;
begin
  with ListBox1 do
  begin
   lstIndex:=SendMessage(Handle, LB_ITEMFROMPOINT, 0, MakeLParam(x,y)) ;
   if (lstIndex >= 0) and (lstIndex <= Items.Count) then
     Hint := Items[lstIndex]
   else
     Hint := ''
   end;
  end;
```

It works, but every time I want to view a hint for another item I have to move my mouse away from the ListBox and then point on another item to see its hint. Is there any way to view hints for every item without moving the mouse away from the ListBox borders?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var fOldIndex: integer = -1;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1MouseMove (Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer) ;
var lstIndex : Integer ;
begin
  with ListBox1 do
  begin
   lstIndex:=SendMessage(Handle, LB_ITEMFROMPOINT, 0, MakeLParam(x,y)) ;

   // this should do the trick..
   if fOldIndex <> lstIndex then
     Application.CancelHint;
   fOldIndex := lstIndex;

   if (lstIndex >= 0) and (lstIndex <= Items.Count) then
     Hint := Items[lstIndex]
   else
     Hint := ''
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't (lstIndex <= Items.Count) actually be (lstIndex < Items.Count)

Comment: The search result said the value of LB_ITEMFROMPOINT is $01a9. But which unit declares this value?

Comment: You should set the ListBox1.ShowHint property value to TRUE first.